# Visual Studio 2012 CallerMemberName could not be found

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 so I could take advantage of better ways to implement MVVM with Silverlight.

The first thing I wanted to do is start using the [CallerMemberName] attribute so I didn't have to hard-code property name strings.

I created a new Silverlight app, created a new class, included 'using System.Runtime.CompilerServices', and proceeded to type [CallerMemberName]. However, I get the error:

"The type or namespace name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

However, I did include the using directive and there are no other assemblies that need to be referenced.

This is driving me up the wall since no Google search returned any information about why I might not be able to use it in VS2012/Silverlight. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Silverlight?

Comment: Silverlight 5. I've tried it in VS2013 now, and I get the same - not found.

Comment: Right, because the attribute isn't part of Silverlight 5. You can either create your own as per the answer from SLaks, or use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/

Comment: Not sure I get why it's not part of Silverlight 5. Is it available for previous versions?

Comment: Well the attribute was introduced in .NET 4.5, which was released considerably later than Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the version of Silverlight you're targetting doesn't include that attribute.

However, that's OK; you can simply define it yourself:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
    sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```